# What is the standard connector on reusable whip cream dispensers?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pneumatic, connections

The male connection on a reusable whip cream dispenser cannister where charger cartridges are placed appears to be a standard size, as caps that are used to push and hold the charger cartridge are sold individually and work with any brand whip cream dispenser.

I am trying to figure out what type of male connection that is.  I measured it at roughly 21.7mm or 0.858 inches.  Using a thread gauge tool I measured the thread at 2.0 metric or 13 US TPI.

In the picture below it is the male connection at the bottom/center.

[image: Male Charger Connection]

I am trying to determine what connection component is needed to attach a pressurized line to the cream dispenser but so far have not been able to find anything that matches my measurements. Is anyone aware of what I will need to form this pneumatic connection?

I tried a CGA-320 nut which was too small for this connection.  I also tried a 7/8" tank supply line fitting, which was too large.

Here are examples of existing pressure regulators that fit that connection.  They appear to either be a bronze adaptor piece with a push connect pneumatic fitting, or a single component.

[image: connection type 1]

[image: connection type 2]

Comment: The thread should be easy, but what about the spigot part?

Comment: you could modify an empty gas cartridge

Comment: I would suspect that it is not a commonly used thread, such as a "Dairy Thread": http://www.frankberg.nl/dairy-couplings-DIN11851.html

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far.  I am going to use the normal spigot attachments, its the other connection that I am looking for details on.

Comment: The gas cartridge cannot be used because it is just held in place by the "cartridge holder".  I did look into modifying one of those as it fits that connection, but the inside of the far end is rounded  to mate up with the gas cartridge and has an offset hole, so that makes it hard to just drill and bolt on a pneumatic connection

I believe it could be an M22-2.0 connection but am having a hard time finding any adaptors or pneumatic connections in that size to test out.

Answer (score 1):

The gas connection on the whipped cream dispenser is M22*2.  Actually had to reach out to a Chinese manufacturer for that because GreatWhip didn't ever get back to me.

I am going to be trying to find some adaptors or something to fit to a standard N2 tank. If I am successful, I'll post back.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the connection!  Please do follow up if you are able to find an adaptor that will work with that M22*2 connection, as it sounds like we are both trying to do something similar.

Comment: @TomEdwards definitely will.  If you break it before me, please do the same.  I don't know why this seems like such a trade secret. 
  
The closest I've been able to find is 2.5*2, so I am still trying to figure out where I can find one.  Thought I had one, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

@BrewerJack, any update on this? I am trying to add to an adapter to my ISI container too.